# How to open new browser window on a client, rather than a server

Tags: jsp

This question has been asked before, but does not have an answer yet:

I'm trying to use *"java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(java.net.URI.create(myURL));"* in a client/server application.

I want the default browser to open on the client side when the client clicks on a button. What happens is that the browser opens on the server. How can I fix it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use the JavaScript [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open) method in the generated source, e.g.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  var windowObjectReference;
  var strWindowFeatures = "menubar=yes,location=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes";
  windowObjectReference = window.open("http://www.example.com/", "WindowName", strWindowFeatures);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't run at webbrowser. It runs at webserver. It's HTML/CSS/JS which runs at webbrowser. You need to solve this by HTML/CSS/JS. CSS is incapable for this. JS can do this with `window.open`, but that's overcomplicated if you can just use HTML `target="_blank"` in a link/form.

E.g.

```
<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">Click to view Google in a new window</a>
```

or

```
<form action="http://google.com" target="_blank">
    <input type="submit" value="Press to view Google in a new window" />
</form>
```

This will open the target in a new window/tab.